# Get value from one of the non-empty fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Consider I have a collection in MongoDB that has two fields: `foo` and `bar`. I'm building an aggregation pipeline and I want to compute another field (`baz`) that contains value either from `foo` if it's set or from `bar` in this specific order.

The behavior should be equivalent to the following JavaScript code:

```js
const baz = foo ?? bar;
```

What would be the most optimal way to achieve this?

Comment: Have you checked out [$ifNull](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`$ifNull`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator for that:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      "aOrB": {
        "$ifNull": [
          "$a",
          "$b"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See this [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/nXl3bvmiqcM).